# Spring JPA method name validator

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Spring JpaRepository can generate SQL query from interface method name:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {
    List<SomeEntity> findAllByEntityId(Long id);
    List<SomeEntity> findAllByEntityIdAndDateOfCreationBetweenAnd/*...*/(Long id, /*...*/);
}
```

As you can see - it can be complicated. So it's possible that method name won't be correct and compiler errors occurs.

**Question:**

Is it possible to check/validate method name before using it in real project (which require some compile time, trial and error)?

Or maybe it is possible to convert such method name to SQL before usage - to see if this method name is valid and if it do all operation right?

Of course the obvious method is to make smaller project for test only. But I feel that it must be better way.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Spring does validate that the methods translate correctly to **JPQL**. So the query should always be syntactically correct. But it doesn't mean it will do what you expect it to do. That's why you should write automated tests. Also, it's not a *compiler* error that would occur, but a *runtime* error.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a test using a test database and Spring test runner. There are multiple ways to do that, so I'll just give a rough sketch to get you started:

- Instead of your real DataSource Spring bean, create a test DataSource bean using an in-memory (eg. [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)) database
- Create a Spring test context, that will:

  - discover your entities
  - set up the DB schema (eg. using [`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-misc-properties))
  - optionally pre-fill the DB with some data (eg. using [`hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-misc-properties))
  - enable and discover your Spring Data repositories
- Use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` to run your tests with JUnit.
- Use `@ContextConfiguration` to point to your test Spring context
- Use `@Transactional` to make the tests transactional and have any changes done in test methods rolled back automatically
- `@Autowire` the `EntityManager` and the Spring Data repositories and use them in tests.

See Spring docs on [Integration Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this, but....

If you want to test the name of the method without compiling the interface you can find a class called **PartTree** in **org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser** in the **spring-data-commons:1.12.6** jar.

> new PartTree(stringVersionOfMethodName,classOfEntityRepoIsFor)

It will throw an exception if it can't parse the name properly.

For maven I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent of 1.4.3.RELEASE and including the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa depedency